# MVC Razor @Functions create textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using vNext (MVC6 with Core 5.0).

I declared 'functions' in one of my Views and within I have a method wherewith I would like to create a textbox and add this to the view.

```
@functions {
    public void CreateTextBox()
    {
        @Html.Raw(@Html.TextBox("a", "b"));
    }
}
```

This doesn't create a textbox element, but if I execute the code below, there is an textbox created:

```
@functions {
    public HtmlString CreateTextBox()
    {
        return @Html.TextBox("a", "b");
    }
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.Raw(CreateTextBox());
}
```

My question is: Is it possible to create a textbox via the CreateTextBox()-method without returning anything and without using the Html.BeginForm()? So is there a way to make the first option work?

Comment: how are you calling first option in view?

Comment: Why so much use of `@Html.Raw`? That seems unnecessary. Why don't you want to return anything from your function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a helper. Functions are for stuff that actually should be in a ViewModel (i.e. translate model values to printable values), helpers are there to help output HTML.

Stick this in your App_Code directory in a file named `FormHelpers.cshtml`:

```
@helper PrintFormWithOneTextBox
{
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.TextBox("a", "b");
    }
}
```

Then you can call it using `@FormHelpers.PrintFormWithOneTextBox()`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. Is it also possible to add javascript in the using(Html.BeginForm()) within a helper?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "add javascript". You can do about everything MVC can do in a helper.

Answer (score -2):

There is no need of **function** and **@Html.BeginForm()**. Just put  **@Html.Raw(@Html.TextBox("a", "b"));** to your HTML code where you want to place a text box it will render a text box.

Comment: I want to do it with a function.

Comment: What is your scenario, can you please explain, and why you don't want to use return ?